# useState React passing color

Tags: reactjs, use-state

I am new to react and currently working on how to dynamically change the color of some text in my document. What I want to happen is that when the user clicks the "Click Me!" button the color of the words in the h2 tag change. It is not working and in the React tools I am getting an error that I am not sure how to fix.

App.js

```
import Start from './Start'
import './App.css';
import { useState } from 'react';

function App() {
  const [name, setName] = useState('Becky');
  const [color, setColor] = useState("#F0F8FF");
  const myArt = {color: {color}}
  

  const assetChange = (()=>{
    setName('Ethan');
    setColor("#FF7F50");
    
})

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Start name={name}/>
      <h2 style={myArt}>Change my Color</h2>
      <button onClick={() => assetChange()}>Click Me!</button>
      
      {console.log(myArt)}
      
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

The error that I am getting in the console is the below

[image: Console Error]

Comment: Also, no need to wrap a function in parentheses: `const assetChange = (()=>{...`

Answer (score 2):

`const myArt = {color: {color}}`

expands to:

```
const myArt = {color: {color: 'the color' }}
```

What you want to write is this:

```
const myArt = {color}
```

Answer (score 2):

you should change

`myArt = { color: {color} }`

to

`myArt = { color: color }`